# How to check if user is using touchpad?

Tags: c++, qt, input, mouse, qt5

Is there any way to check if a user is using a touchpad or conventional mouse in Qt? I would like to implement different scrolling behaviors in an OpenGL program based on which input device is being used.

Comment: [`QTouchEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html) and `QEvent::TouchBegin`

Comment: It doesn't appear that QTouchEvent has specific methods for scrolling. Would I have to work that out myself using the touch points?

Comment: Yout question was to determinate using touchpad. If `QEvent::TouchBegin` happened the touchpad in action, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I'll see if I can use that.

Comment: Please keep in mind that some of us are on laptops and have both a touchpad and a mouse at the same time.